# How to record each input separately in a loop separately? (Java)

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

My problem is that only the 5th input gets printed while the rest is not

```
Scanner ns = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = 0;

int i=1;  
while(i<=5)
{  
    System.out.println("enter a number");  
    n = ns.nextInt();
    i++;  
}  

System.out.println(+n);
System.out.println(+n);
System.out.println(+n);
System.out.println(+n);
System.out.println(+n);
```

Let's say I typed 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 respectively,
it should look like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But instead I get

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Comment: Move the `System.out.println(n)` statement inside the while loop. Or store the input in a map in the while loop and print the contents of the map afterwards. Your variable `n` is overridden each time inside the while loop, so afterwards it only contains the latest value.

Comment: What you are doing in here is updating the value of same variable(storage space) in the loop. You would need 5 separate storage spaces to save the values of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your input parameters into `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ns = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    int i = 1;
    List<Integer> params = new ArrayList<>();
    while (i <= 5) {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        n = ns.nextInt();
        params.add(n);
        i++;
    }
    for (Integer param : params) {
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
enter a number
2
enter a number
3
enter a number
4
enter a number
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

All the inputs are being printed, the problem is that the while loop sets n to the value of 5 and then you print 5 five times. The correct code you are looking for is:

```
int n = 0;

int i=1;  
while(i<=5)
{  
  System.out.println("enter a number");  
  n = ns.nextInt();
  i++;  
  System.out.println(+n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please print number in loop. See code below :

```
   Scanner ns = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;

    int i=1;  
    while(i<=5)
    {  
    System.out.println("enter a number");  
    n = ns.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n);
    i++;  
    }
```